# JDWP error: No agent option specified: address, while remote debugging java app

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, remote-debugging

I am trying to connect to a java application running on a remote machine which is run using IBM java environment.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/bin/java" -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket, suspend=y, address=8080, ............."
```

And getting erros,

```
INFO: [Agent.cpp:332] JDWP error: No agent option specified: address
JVMJ9TI064E Agent initialization function Agent_OnLoad failed for library jdwp, return code -1
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti26(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
```

There are no questions, forums discussing this error with IBM java jdk.

I am an beginner in java and would be happy to get some help here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include spaces between the comma-separated portion of the option.

E.g. do:

`java -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 ...`